# Finding solution to fourth order polynomial

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials, homework

I would have your opinion on this. So, we were assigned some questions to solve using the program Mathematica, but I am not sure how my teacher would like the solution to be presented.

Could someone show an example of how they would've solved it? Because we were not given an example.

Here's the instruction:

"This task involves solving a number of mathematical problems using Mathematica and writing a short report directly in your own Notebook. The report must, for each task, describe: the problem, figure, specify names of variables, the solution to the problem including reasoning and then discuss the result."

This is an example polynomial equation of which solutions should be found:

$$4x^{4}-\frac{64}{3} x^{3}+\frac{149}{6}x^{2}+\frac{49}{2} x-51=0$$

"The graph must also be drawn for the polynomial, and the zeros must be marked with a red dot.”

Comment: Use [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html). Examples are in the documentation

Comment: @Bob Hanlon That's not what's being asked for, I think. It's being said ”Could someone show an example of how they would've solved it?”

Comment: @Ericleast992 That would be equivalent to doing OP's homework for them.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. The introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a [fast intro for math students](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) as well as a [fast intro for programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) to choose from.

Comment: @MarcoB this is not my homework, the question is not the homework question itself.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be either a homework question or a self-learning exercise. Such questions are welcome as long as the OP shows all the meaningful work done so far and seeks clarification regarding specific items that they can't resolve themselves.

Answer (score 1):

You can plot with `Plot`, and you can draw extra stuff on it with the `Epilog->` option.  The extra stuff might be [graphics directives](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/GraphicsDirectives.html) like colors and `Disk`s and `Line`s (I'm specifically not mentioning a particular primitive that suits your question):

```
Plot[ E^Sin@x-1, {x,-10,10}, 
  Epilog -> {
    Blue,Disk[{-Pi,0},Scaled@.05],
    Red,Thickness@.02,Line@{{0,E-1},{3,E-1}}
  }
]
```

[image: example plot]

You'll have to enter in the right functions and coordinates in order to get the plot you want, perhaps using `Solve` as others have mentioned.

Comment: Such solutions are being traded on dedicated sites. Typically, here we first want to see the poster efforts and ask what have you tried before posting a solution.

Comment: I'm pretty new to Wolfram Mathematica, my teacher didn't give us enough time to familiarize ourselves with the program before solve these questions. There's some things that I am not familiar with it when writing the solution itself on the program, you mentioned graphics directives and the epilog option, and while I have read this stuff on Wolfram help documentation, it still hasn't been clear to me what it does in ELI5-terms.

Secondly, you write some things in your code, but I am not sure what it does or what it means. For example: 

"Disk[{-Pi,0},Scaled@.05]" or "Line@{{0,E-1},{3,E-1}”

Comment: @Bryan, in lieu of yarchick's comment, let's see some examples of what you have tried instead of me presenting things that may or may not be within reach.